# How to convert a sting field to an ObjectId inside of an array of of objects via MongoDb Shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

So my MongoDb doc looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1842d238ec58056d94bbb3"),
    "itemsPurchased" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5e7365360665d10011756af2",
            "created" : "2020-03-19T12:27:34.108Z",
            "productLine" : "5ce8ec9df5cc72002fee0d4e",
            "price" : 1.9,
            "tax" : 7,
            "ean" : "42272120",
            "expirationDate" : "2020-06-17T12:27:34.103Z",
            "kiosk" : "5c17a3d963ca649138ec522c",
            "loadCell" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5e7365360665d10011756af3",
            "created" : "2020-03-19T12:27:34.108Z",
            "productLine" : "5ce8ec9df5cc72002fee0d4e",
            "price" : 1.9,
            "tax" : 7,
            "ean" : "42272120",
            "expirationDate" : "2020-06-17T12:27:34.103Z",
            "kiosk" : "5c17a3d963ca649138ec522c",
            "loadCell" : "1"
        }
    ],
    "paymentMethod" : [],
    "type" : "purchase",
    "total" : NumberDecimal("3.8"),
    "session" : ObjectId("5f1842bf1f2028e369d945f0"),
    "orgId" : ObjectId("5cddce9a51cbb2002d636741"),
    "created" : ISODate("2020-07-22T13:44:50.973Z"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2020-07-22T13:44:50.973Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The problem is that inside the itemsPurchased[] (due to a logical err) there are ids of type string. Here for example `"_id" : "5e7365360665d10011756af2"` and `"productLine" : "5ce8ec9df5cc72002fee0d4e"`. How do I go through all documents that have an object in the itemsPurchased[] that has strings instead of ObjectIds and convert them to be of type ObjectId. I tried to use $convert and $toObjectId toghether with $map but can't seem to get it right.

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "itemsPurchased._id": {$type: "string"}}},
  { "$set": "itemsPurchased1": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$itemsPurchased",
        "in": {
          "$toObjectId": [
            "$$this",
            {
              "productLine": {
                "$toObjectId": "$$this.productLine"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can't get the map part right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used correctly `$toObjectId`, You just need to change `$mergeObjects` instead of `$toObjectId`, when you merge with `$$this` inside `$map`,

```
  {
    "$set": {
      "itemsPurchased1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$itemsPurchased",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": ["$$this", { "productLine": { "$toObjectId": "$$this.productLine" } }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j9toB1d2gpY)

---

#### updateMany

```
db.transactions.updateMany({}, 
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "itemsPurchased": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$itemsPurchased",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": ["$$this", { "productLine": { "$toObjectId": "$$this.productLine" } }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: how to do this for updateMany op, aggregation pipe does not save the results

Comment: you have not mentioned for update in your question, can you provide how you are updating with updateMany after i will correct it.

Comment: actually, all I wanted to do was to update those string ids, but managed to ask the question wrongly ... so aggregation works perfect, the way you showed me, but I did not know the aggregation results do not get written back to the DB ... tried to play around and adopt the query to updateMany, so far no result ...

Comment: what are you getting exactly in response and where you executing this query? i have tested its working fine,

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('transactions').update(
{"itemsPurchased.kiosk":{$type: "string"}}, 
[{
    "$set": {
      "itemsPurchased": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$itemsPurchased",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "kiosk": {
                  "$toObjectId": "$$this.kiosk"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }], 
{multi:true})
```

This is how to update ...